# Error getting JSON Map<String, Object> with SpringMVC and Jackson2

Tags: json, spring, spring-mvc, jakarta-ee, jackson

I'm trying to get a Map where there are a **'number'** with the number of actions and **'actions'** with a list of actions.
I've checked the list of actions in java and it works just fine.

I have 4 actions and in json file I'm getting right just the first one.

**Controller in java**

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/getactions/{idTask}", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = "application/json")
@ResponseBody
public Map<String, Object> getActions(Principal principal,
        @PathVariable Long idTask) {
    logger.info("Task controller get actions...");

    List<TaskAction> actions = null;

    if (principal == null) {
        actions = new ArrayList<TaskAction>();
    } else {
        actions = taskActionService.getAllTaskActions(idTask);
    }

    System.out.println(">>>>>>>>Task Controller - Actions>>>>>>>>>>>>> "
            + actions.size());
    for (TaskAction ta : actions) {
        System.out.println(">>>>>>>>ta: " + ta.getActionname());
    }
    System.out.println(">>>>>>>>END getAllActions()>>>>>>>>>>>>> ");

    Map<String, Object> data = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    data.put("actions", actions);
    data.put("number", actions.size());

    return data;
}
```

**Sysout**

```
>>>>>>>>Task Controller - Actions>>>>>>>>>>>>> 4
>>>>>>>>ta: tacometer
>>>>>>>>ta: hola
>>>>>>>>ta: hi there
>>>>>>>>ta: other action
>>>>>>>>END getAllActions()>>>>>>>>>>>>>
```

I'm not getting any error, but the json result only gets the first element in the action list and the id of the rest of actions.

**json that I get from http...getactions/8**

```
{  
   "number":4,
   "actions":[  
      { ... },
      3,
      4,
      5
   ]
}
```

The ... is the first action that is well recovered. (I've avoided to write the code for clearity)

Any ideas about what could it be?

Thanks in advance.

---

**Example of json with 2 actions**

```
{
    "number": 2,
    "actions": [{
        "idTaskAction": 4,
        "task": {
            "idTask": 8,
            "taskname": "abbbbbbbbbbbbbb",
            "description": "fffffffffffffffqqqqq",
            "date": 1389569940000,
            "deadline": -23918633280000,
            "category": {
                "idTaskCategory": 1,
                "sortOrder": 0,
                "categoryname": "cat1",
                "timestamp": 1402437394000
            },
            "priority": {
                "idTaskPriority": 1,
                "sortOrder": 0,
                "aka": "none",
                "priorityname": "low",
                "timestamp": 1402437527000
            },
            "state": {
                "idTaskState": 1,
                "statename": "pending"
            },
            "user": {
                "idUser": 1,
                "username": "joe"
            },
            "userResponsible": {
                "idUser": 1,
                "username": "joe"
            },
            "evaluation": "12345678saad",
            "pending": 0,
            "actions": [{
                "idTaskAction": 2,
                "task": 8,
                "date": 1402652358000,
                "actionname": "tacometer",
                "description": "asfdafa",
                "duration": 12,
                "user": {
                    "idUser": 1,
                    "username": "joe"
                },
                "timestamp": 1411493866000
            },
            {
                "idTaskAction": 3,
                "task": 8,
                "date": 1404207558000,
                "actionname": "hola",
                "description": "un dos tres",
                "duration": 20,
                "user": {
                    "idUser": 1,
                    "username": "joe"
                },
                "timestamp": 1405022827000
            },
            4,
            {
                "idTaskAction": 5,
                "task": 8,
                "date": 1412164741000,
                "actionname": "other action",
                "description": "ya me my",
                "duration": 22,
                "user": {
                    "idUser": 1,
                    "username": "joe"
                },
                "timestamp": 1411733131000
            }],
            "timestamp": 1411733131000
        },
        "date": 1412074440000,
        "actionname": "hi there",
        "description": "lkjÃ±lkj ya",
        "duration": 25,
        "user": {
            "idUser": 1,
            "username": "joe"
        },
        "timestamp": 1411733090000
    },
    5]
}
```

Comment: are you able to get actions ? and if yes what is the output in java ? and how are you creating file.json with action object ?

Comment: @Benjamin Spring works over javaee. Without javaee Spring wouldn't work. Where do you get misled?

Comment: @Ashish Yes I getactions in java and through url .../getactions/x I get json file. Jackson makes the magic, its translate the map into json. Now I post the java sysout that I'm getting.

Comment: so am assuming the logic to convert java object to JSON object is inside getAllTaskActions ?

Comment: That function is List<TaskAction> getAllTaskActions(long idTask) and return List<TaskAction>. Here you have an easy example of Jackson http://norrisshelton.com/2012/07/15/spring-3-mvc-with-json-via-jackson-2-0/

Comment: What is `file.json`? Can you give a short and reproducible example with a manually created `Map` of `TaskAction`s?

Comment: file.json is what I get from the url. I added an example with 2 actions, as you can see by the end of the file there is a 5 alone, that is the id from de second taskaction but it lacks of all data.

Comment: I don't see anything that would explain this. Please post your object structure.

Comment: I think I'm starting to find out. It seems that I have some recursive protection related with @JsonIdentityInfo that avoid to repeat an object in json. A Task has some TaskActions, so when the first taskaction is loaded is automatically loaded task and taskactions recursively.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that the classes Task, User... has @JsonIdentityInfo with ObjectIdGenerator.PropertyGenerator.class option so when Jackson try to serialize the object into json, if the object it is already in the file, then it is not added again. This way avoid to serialize json file with infinite recursions.

To solve this we need to change ObjectIdGenerator.PropertyGenerator.class for **ObjectIdGenerator.None.class** so that the objects are serialized even if they are already part of other objects.

Change

```
@JsonIdentityInfo(generator = ObjectIdGenerators.PropertyGenerator.class, property = "@id")
```

for

```
@JsonIdentityInfo(generator = ObjectIdGenerators.None.class, property = "@id")
```